# Proving that $X$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If we're given that some $X\subset G $ such that $e\in X$, and $\forall g \in G$, cosets $gX$ partition $G$, is $X$ a subgroup of $G$?

I'm not quite sure what it is I have to do. If $X$ wasn't a subgroup, then you can't say the cosets of $X$ are an equivalence class of $X$ since you would need inverses and closure (symmetry, transitivity, reflexivity).

Can someone please provide some hints?

Comment: Hint: (i) for
$H:=\{h\in G\mid hX=X\}$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$; (ii) since $e\in X$ and since left cosets of $X$ partition $G$, 
$gX=X\iff gX\cap X\ne\emptyset\iff g\in X$.
Combining (i) and (ii), $H=X$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your conjecture is correct. Here is proof:

Suppose $g \in X$. Then, since $e \in X$, $e=g^{-1}g \in g^{-1}X$, so that by cosets of $X$ partitioning $G$, $g^{-1}X=X$, so that $e \in X \Rightarrow g^{-1}e \in g^{-1}X=X$. This proves that $X$ is closed under inversion map $G \rightarrow G$. For composition, if $g,h \in X$, then $h=he \in hX$, so similarly from above, $hX=X$. Then, $hg \in hX=X$, so that $hg \in X$. This with $e \in X$ proves that $X$ satisfies all axioms of a subgroup, so that $X \subset G$ is a subgroup.